# How to efficiently expose many C++ data members of a single object to QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a C++ object pointer with many data members. I need them all available in QML. One obvious way would be to create a `Q_PROPERTY` for each member so they can be individually accessed via QML. However, if we are talking about dozens of data members, well that's a lot of lines of `Q_PROPERTY`, not to mention having to individually handle these in QML as separate properties as well (especially if dealing with "on changed" signals for each property).

I am wondering if it is possible to make a single `Q_PROPERTY` that would include all the data members I need. But what is not clear to me is the apparent mismatch between [the types that QML supports](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativebasictypes.html) and the types you can list in a `Q_PROPERTY`. For example, in QML, we have a basic `string` but its corresponding lising in a C++ `Q_PROPERTY` must be `QString`:

```
 Q_PROPERTY(QString datastring READ showdata NOTIFY datastringChanged)
  //in QML, `datastring` is just a plain string
```

Would there be more complex properties like lists or arrays that can be easily matched? QML has a `list` type and C++ has the `QList` but are these the same thing? Where can I find a listing of compatible types between C++ and QML?

On the other hand, having individual Q_PROPERTY for each data member could likely be better performance (my data is large and often changing) since the QML would not need to parse anything, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would there be more complex properties like lists or arrays that can
>   be easily matched? QML has a list type and C++ has the QList but are
>   these the same thing? Where can I find a listing of compatible types
>   between C++ and QML?

Have a look at the [C++/JS data conversion help page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html). I think the list missed that `QList<QObject*>` is also possible.

> On the other hand, having individual Q_PROPERTY for each data member
>   could likely be better performance (my data is large and often
>   changing) since the QML would not need to parse anything, perhaps.

Maybe, yes, depends on your performance needs. A C++ QList gets converted to a JavaScript list when accessed from QML/JS. That's a bit of conversion overhead indeed. Also, ff an item in the list changes, you need to emit the notify signal for the complete property, and every JS binding in which the list was used needs to be reevaluated, which will again be many list conversions. That *could* be better by having more fine-grained properties, but it really depends.

Btw, with Qt 5.1 there now is `MEMBER`, which makes writing Q_PROPERTYs a bit easier.

Comment: thanks for pointing out `MEMBER` I hadn't seen that before. So it just basically allows direct access to a data member without an intermediating function as the getter?

Comment: Yep. Basically ``moc`` will auto-generate the getters and setters for you, all you have to provide is a member variable and a ``NOTIFY`` signal.

Comment: It is to be noted that `Q_PROPERTY` using `MEMBER` and defining a `NOTIFY` signal, have Qt emitting this signal on property value change from QML if they have no setter defined. No signal is emitted if you directly change the member value in C++.